# Python3: NameError: name 'open' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        with open('log', 'w+') as fL:
            fL.write('__del__')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TestClass()
```

Ran the script and got the error message: NameError: name 'open' is not defined

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you give any more information?

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message.

Comment: @DYZ Exception ignored in: <function TestClass.__del__ at 0x000001C8597A3400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in __del__
NameError: name 'open' is not defined

Comment: Do not call your files `test.py`.

Comment: @DYZ I renamed the file and got the same error message.

Comment: Also remove the folder `__pycache__`, if any, and restart python.

Comment: @DYZ It didn't help to delete __pycache__. Is the issue reproduced at your side?

Comment: @Ariel A What information do you need?

Comment: No, it works fine. Is this the full code that you run? No other `import`s, etc.?

Comment: @DYZ It's the full code. I got the same error on my Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Comment: @DYZ It works fine on python2.

Comment: Can you `open` any files at all?

Comment: @DYZ Yes, I can.

Comment: Here's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422188/why-am-i-getting-nameerror-global-name-open-is-not-defined-in-del