# Python, pass by reference but argument returns unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python, with some background in C & Javascript.

I have the following two functions and test cases:

```
def switch(a, b):
    print("switch__You gave me (%d, %d)." % (a,b))
    y = a
    a = b 
    b = y
    print("switch__The order is now (%d, %d)" % (a, b))

def sortHi_Low(c, d):
    print("SORT You gave me (%d, %d)." % (c,d))
    if (c < d):
        switch(c, d)
        print("SORT The order is now (%d, %d)" % (c, d))
    else:
        print("SORT The order did not change (%d, %d)" % (c, d))

print("Case 1 \n")
sortHi_Low(10, 3)

print("\nCase 2 \n")
sortHi_Low(4,5)
```

`switch()` works as anticipated. `sortHi_Low()`runs `switch()`, but always returns the numbers in the same order they have been passed in.

My understanding with Python is that objects are always passed by reference. When `switch` took in the sort's variables as parameters, it should have changed their value by reference - then the sort should have returned those new values. However, this is what prints in the interpreter.

```
Case 1

SORT You gave me (10, 3).
SORT The order did not change (10, 3)

Case 2

SORT You gave me (4, 5).
switch__You gave me (4, 5).
switch__The order is now (5, 4)
SORT The order is now (4, 5)
```

The sort should go Hi to Low, but does not work.

Comment: Your understanding is [wrong](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm)

Comment: Briefly: `switch(c, d)` doesn't change `c` and `d` because everything in `switch` is a local variable.

Comment: Also see [this question about passing objects by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

Comment: Also note: Python `tuple` packing and sequence unpacking make swapping so trivial it's not worth factoring out into a separate function: `a, b = b, a` is the canonical way to swap, requiring no temporary names at all.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139424/call-destructor-of-an-element-from-a-list/34140055#34140055) is related and should help you, too. Also read [this article](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/).