# python ctypes garbage collection

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using ctypes to access a c library (it is really c++ code) from python:

```
class CRMeAnnotationList(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.obj = lib.CRMeAnnotationList_new()de
def __del__(self):
    if self.obj:
        lib.CRMeAnnotationList_destroy(self.obj)
lst = CRMeAnnotationList()
```

The C code looks like this

```
extern "C" {__declspec(dllexport) CRMeAnnotationList* CRMeAnnotationList_new() 
                { return new CRMeAnnotationList(); 
                }
            __declspec(dllexport)void CRMeAnnotationList_destroy(CRMeAnnotationList* p)
                {
                if (p)
                    delete p;
                }
            }
```

This code gives me
finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

whereas if I do not destroy the pointer I get 0 as exit code.

Does this mean, that I do not need to destroy that pointer i.e execute the destructor part **del** in the python code?

Comment: You should not use del. it’s not working the way you think it works. And can cause weird problems, posisbly the one you see. Try allocating your C++-object without a wrapper class, and then deallocate. And see what happens. And there is no magic removing the Object, so you DO need to call the destroy.

Comment: Show a complete [mcve].  Have you set `.argtypes` and `.restype` for your functions?  Did you create `lib` correctly?  At a guess, you are using 64-bit Python so and the pointer returned by `new` is truncated to 32-bits due to not setting `.restype`.  The default return type is `c_int` (32-bits).

Comment: @deets: Can you justify that position? `__del__` looks very suitable to me here.

Comment: The looks are deceiving ;) There is actually no guarantee that `__del__` is being run at all. If it is run, there is no guarantee about the order of things - a common occurrence is that necessary modules (e.g. ctypes in this case) are being GCed *before* the destructor is run, obviously making it fail. This is one of the reasons `with` has been introduced. For a discussion with follow-ups, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104535/i-dont-understand-this-python-del-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running 64-bit Python and haven't set `.argtypes` and `.restype` properly.

Example:

**test.cpp**

```
#define API __declspec(dllexport) // Windows-specific

extern "C" {

struct CRMeAnnotationList {
    int a;
};

API CRMeAnnotationList* CRMeAnnotationList_new() {
    return new CRMeAnnotationList();
}

API void CRMeAnnotationList_destroy(CRMeAnnotationList* p) {
    if(p)
        delete p;
}

}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL('test')
lib.CRMeAnnotationList_new.argtypes = None
lib.CRMeAnnotationList_new.restype = c_void_p
lib.CRMeAnnotationList_destroy.argtypes = c_void_p,
lib.CRMeAnnotationList_destroy.restype = None

class CRMeAnnotationList:

    def __init__(self):
        print(f'created   {id(self):#x}')
        self.obj = lib.CRMeAnnotationList_new()

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'destroyed {id(self):#x}')
        if self.obj:
            lib.CRMeAnnotationList_destroy(self.obj)

lst = CRMeAnnotationList()
```

Output:

```
created   0x2232dfc35c0
destroyed 0x2232dfc35c0
```

Output when `.argtypes` and `.restype` lines are commented out:

```
created   0x1c98e8f35c0
destroyed 0x1c98e8f35c0
Exception ignored in: <function CRMeAnnotationList.__del__ at 0x000001C98E9176A8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\metolone\Desktop\test.py", line 16, in __del__
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFF8C6CABCF
```

Note the address of the access violation.  It is a 32-bit value sign-extended to 64-bits.

Comment: Should `argtypes` be set to `()` instead of `None` for the function taking 0 arguments?

Comment: @Eric Note `tuple()` not `()` is an empty tuple.  The docs do state passing tuple of arguments, but 'None` and `[]` work correctly as well.

Comment: @Mark('32bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: @prodnik Are you saying you are running 32-bit WindowsPE?  Set `.argtypes` and `.restype` anyway, but update your question with a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, as I have, if you want more help.

Comment: @Mark print (platform.architecture()) gives ('32bit', 'WindowsPE') and everything else works fine. (The code gets some complex data from an xml file.) But thanks for the example, I have a closer look. And by the way i am planning to use 64 bit python 3, but for now this is pythonn 2.7 code.

Comment: @prudnik My systems says `('64-bit','windowsPE')`  but it is Windows 10.  `platform.platform()` seems to be more accurate.  In any case update your question with an an [mcve] and mention OS and Python version.

Comment: _"`tuple()` not `()` is an empty tuple"_ - Not only are both empty tuples, but both are the _same_ empty tuple. `tuple() is ()` gives `True` on my machine.

Comment: I have set .argtypes and .restype like you said. I exits with code 0. So that seems to be the solution to the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Eric Sorry, I was thinking of for example `(5)` vs. `(5,)`.  The first is not a tuple.  I'm in the habit of not relying on parentheses for tuples, since `x = 5,` and `x=1,2,3` are also a tuples.  *Explicit is better than implicit* :^)