# Closing SQLite3 connections in Python (when connection is part of an object)

Tags: oop, database-design, sqlite, python-3.x, cursor

I have been trying to find an answer to this question all night and I still haven't come across a definite answer. Normally when I work with sqlite3 i would use the following pattern:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('whatever.db')
cursor = db.cursor()

#do some stuff

cursor.close()
```

Now I trying to evolve my understanding of OOP and databases so I thought I would create a controller object to interact with the database. I have come up with the following:

A class which just defines the connection and cursor:

```
import sqlite3

class coffee_shop_controller:

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect("coffeeshop.db")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
```

I subclass this for the various controllers that I need. For example:

```
class customer_controller(coffee_shop_controller):

    """creates a controller to add/delete/amend customer records in the
       coffee shop database"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def add_customer(self,fn,ln,sa,t,pc,tn):
        sql = """insert into customer
                 (first_name,last_name,street_address,town,post_code,telephone_number)
                 values
                 ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')""".format(fn,ln,sa,t,pc,tn)
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.db.commit()
```

I appreciate that the design pattern may not be great (open to suggestions) and that I really should be preventing SQL injection but the closing the connection is interesting me at the moment.

From searching around the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#sqlite3) the comment line suggests that we ***can*** close the connection, not that we ***must***. Is this right? Do I not really need to bother?

If I do need to bother then there seems to be a split on what I should do:

- Manually close the connection
- [Use the `__del__` method](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/)
- [Use `with` or `atexit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974813/cleaning-up-an-internal-pysqlite-connection-on-object-destruction)

Is there anything definitive here? The `__del__` method makes the most sense to me but maybe that's my ignorance talking.

Thanks for any suggestions you can offer.

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to free the resources that you do not need anymore. Normally, database connections are pretty "expensive" and I would definitely recommend to open the connection, do the actual query and close the connection right after that.

In order to achieve a better control over this, I would also recommend to follow the **Unit Of Work** design pattern. Moreover, it will be great for you if you can combine **Unit Of Work** with some good **ORM** (such as SQLAlchemy or Django)