# How to do cleanup reliably in python?

Tags: python, ctypes, cyclic-reference

I have some ctypes bindings, and for each body.New I should call body.Free. The library I'm binding doesn't have allocation routines insulated out from the rest of the code (they can be called about anywhere there), and to use couple of useful features I need to make cyclic references.

I think It'd solve if I'd find a reliable way to hook destructor to an object. (weakrefs would help if they'd give me the callback just *before* the data is dropped.

So obviously this code megafails when I put in velocity_func:

```
class Body(object):
    def __init__(self, mass, inertia):
        self._body = body.New(mass, inertia)

    def __del__(self):
        print '__del__ %r' % self
        if body:
            body.Free(self._body)

    ...        

    def set_velocity_func(self, func):
        self._body.contents.velocity_func = ctypes_wrapping(func)
```

I also tried to solve it through weakrefs, with those the things seem getting just worse, just only largely more unpredictable.

Even if I don't put in the velocity_func, there will appear cycles at least then when I do this:

```
class Toy(object):
    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body.owner = self

...

def collision(a, b, contacts):
    whatever(a.body.owner)
```

So how to make sure Structures will get garbage collected, even if they are allocated/freed by the shared library?

There's repository if you are interested about more details: http://bitbucket.org/cheery/ctypes-chipmunk/

Comment: See this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object/865272#865272](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object/865272#865272)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If weakrefs aren't broken, I guess this may work:

```
from weakref import ref

pointers = set()

class Pointer(object):
    def __init__(self, cfun, ptr):
        pointers.add(self)
        self.ref = ref(ptr, self.cleanup)
        self.data = cast(ptr, c_void_p).value # python cast it so smart, but it can't be smarter than this.
        self.cfun = cfun

    def cleanup(self, obj):
        print 'cleanup 0x%x' % self.data
        self.cfun(self.data)
        pointers.remove(self)

def cleanup(cfun, ptr):
    Pointer(cfun, ptr)
```

I yet try it. The important piece is that the Pointer doesn't have any strong references to the foreign pointer, except an integer. This should work if ctypes doesn't free memory that I should free with the bindings. Yeah, it's basicly a hack, but I think it may work better than the earlier things I've been trying.

Edit: Tried it, and it seem to work after small finetuning my code. A surprising thing is that even if I got **del** out from all of my structures, it seem to still fail. Interesting but frustrating.

Neither works, from some weird chance I've been able to drop away cyclic references in places, but things stay broke.

Edit: Well.. weakrefs WERE broken after all! so there's likely no solution for reliable cleanup in python, except than forcing it being explicit.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do, that is create an object that allocates things and then deallocates automatically when the object is no longer in use, is almost impossible in Python, unfortunately. The **del** statement is not guaranteed to be called, so you can't rely on that.

The standard way in Python is simply:

```
try:
    allocate()
    dostuff()
finally:
    cleanup()
```

Or since 2.5 you can also create context-managers and use the with statement, which is a neater way of doing that.

But both of these are primarily for when you allocate/lock in the beginning of a code snippet. If you want to have things allocated for the whole run of the program, you need to allocate the resource at startup, before the main code of the program runs, and deallocate afterwards. There is one situation which isn't covered here, and that is when you want to allocate and deallocate many resources dynamically and use them in many places in the code. For example of you want a pool of memory buffers or similar. But most of those cases are for memory, which Python will handle for you, so you don't have to bother about those. There are of course cases where you want to have dynamic pool allocation of things that are NOT memory, and then you would want the type of deallocation you try in your example, and that *is* tricky to do with Python.

Answer (score -1):

In CPython, `__del__` *is* a reliable destructor of an object, because it will always be called when the reference count reaches zero (note: there may be cases - like circular references of items with `__del__` method defined - where the reference count will never reaches zero, but that is another issue).

**Update**
From the comments, I understand the problem is related to the order of destruction of objects: *body* is a global object, and it is being destroyed before all other objects, thus it is no longer available to them.
Actually, using global objects is not good; not only because of issues like this one, but also because of maintenance.

I would then change your class with something like this

```
class Body(object):
    def __init__(self, mass, inertia):
        self._bodyref = body
        self._body = body.New(mass, inertia)

    def __del__(self):
        print '__del__ %r' % self
        if body:
            body.Free(self._body)

...        

def set_velocity_func(self, func):
    self._body.contents.velocity_func = ctypes_wrapping(func)
```

A couple of notes:

1. The change is only adding a reference to the global *body* object, that thus will live at least as much as all the objects derived from that class.
2. Still, using a global object is not good because of unit testing and maintenance; better would be to have a factory for the object, that will set the correct "body" to the class, and in case of unit test will easily put a mock object. But that's really up to you and how much effort you think makes sense in this project.

Comment: Is __del__ reliable or are you only guessing? "Circular references which are garbage are detected when the option cycle detector is enabled (it’s on by default), but can only be cleaned up if there are no Python-level __del__() methods involved."

Comment: Also, the thing you've described is not a bug. When my apps close, there comes lot of ignored exceptions that yell how they can't call method 'Free' from None. I think from some reason python removes the module before doing the __del__, which is somewhat ironic considering the situation.

Comment: __del__ is NOT reliable. You can not count on __del__ ever being called. It can therefore only be used if the resource is one that the operating system itself will clean up when the app exits, which means memory and filehandles etc.

Comment: __del__ is reliable, because it is being called synchronously, when references to an object reach zero.
Of course, there may be cases with circular references - but it is a completely different matter, tough.

Comment: No, again: You can NOT count on __del__ EVER being called. With or without circular references. From the Python manual:

"It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits. "

__del__ is NOT reliable.  EOF.

Comment: I think it is a matter of perspective. If you expect that __del__ should be called on del, then yes, it will prove unreliable.
If you expect that __del__ will be called when the object reference count reaches zero, then it IS reliable.  
The main point is that circular references (especially when __del__ is declared) will inhibit the reference count to go to zero, and in that case the interpreter will never call __del__, even on exit.
If you are careful (or, if you do not have very complex data structure) it should be enough.

Comment: Definitely not reliable, particularly when the interpreter is exiting. If you need to some cleanup of things for when the Python process exits, never rely on `__del__`.