# Can't call function from destructor in any class

Tags: python

I want use ConfigParser in one class, it needs a call from the destructor, but then strange things happen.

This is my code:

```
"""
function name is 
test  ok!
test1 failed!
test2 failed!
test3 failed!

test4
...  ok!

"""

def test3():
  pass

class Class1:
  def __del__(self):
    test3()

if __name__=="__main__":
  obj=Class1()
```

If the function is named `test1`, `test2` or `test3`, an exception will be raised, and I can't catch it by `try except`.

The traceback is:

```
E:\tc.py
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method Class1.__del__ of <__main__.Class1 instance at 0x00C18F58>> ignored
```

It's so strange! Can you test it in your system? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11):

The order in which objects are destroyed is undefined. This means that by the time `obj.__del__()` is called -- if it's called at all -- `test3()` may or may not have been destroyed.

There is a red box with a warning in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Warning** Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. **Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down)**. For this reason, `__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

In Python, one almost never overrides `__del__`. You should probably rethink your design. See [How do I correctly clean up a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object)

Comment: it's perfect answer. I used to save-work in destructor , just like in C++ . it is mistake in python , I get this red box.

Comment: @weimingzhen: That's right, Python's `__del__` is more similar to Java's finalizers than to C++ destructors. In modern Python, the `with` statement is the correct idiom for freeing up resources (`try`-`finally` being a distant second).

Answer (score 4):

You can't be certain that `test3` hasn't been destroyed by the time `obj.__del__()` is called. Add a reference to it in `Class1.__init__()` if you need to keep it around.