# Why does Python destroy class variables before objects?

Tags: python, class, scope, destructor

I understand that Python doesn't guarantee the order of destruction of objects at the end of the program, or even that it will happen.

So I understand that a class's destructor can't rely on global variables, including other modules.

But I would have thought that objects of the class would have to be destroyed before the class is destroyed. Apparently not:

```
class A(object):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        A.count += 1
        print 'Creating object, there are now', A.count
    def __del__(self):
        A.count -= 1
        print 'Destroying object, there are now', A.count

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
```

On Windows 7 x64 Python v2.7.3 I get:

```
Creating object, there are now 1
Creating object, there are now 2
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'" in <bound
 method A.__del__ of <__main__.A object at 0x0234B8B0>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'" in <bound
 method A.__del__ of <__main__.A object at 0x0234BE90>> ignored
```

I understand the implications of [How do I correctly clean up a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object). But this case is for class (shared or 'static' for my C++ friends) variables. Surely the instance has a reference to the class variable, which should not be destroyed first as we still have a reference to it?

Is it a problem or a mistake to have the class destroyed before objects of that class?
Maybe my question is 'Where are class-shared variables actually stored?"

(Yes, I understand that this can be rectified using a context manager, or even simply:

```
del a1
del a2
```

to destroy the object before the class is destroyed.)

Answer (score 6):

> Maybe my question is 'Where are class-shared variables actually stored?"

If that is your question, the answer is "on the class".

To address your larger question: As you noted, `__del__` can't rely on global variables — but `A` is a global variable, so you can't rely on it.  Interestingly, I can't find an official statement of this in the docs, but there are various references on the internet to this fact that `__del__` can't use global variables.  [Here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/31449-calling-destructor-python-multiply-inherited-class) is one:

> When a Python program terminates the global variables in each module are set to None. The order in which this happens it undefined

It will work if you access the count via `self.__class__.count` instead of `A.count`.  (This is also why it works when you use `self.count`.)

Comment: what about `.__class__` on the instance?

Comment: @FatalError: You're right, the reference issue is a red herring.  The issue is not that the class itself has been deleted, but that the global variable referencing it has been set to None.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Curiously, I get the same behavior when I try it with `.__class__`. It appears as if it's also set to `None` before calling `__del__` in this case, which is kind of surprising.

Comment: @FatalError: Did you change both the `-=` and the `print` to use `self.__class__`?  I thought I saw what you were seeing too, but I was still doing `print A.count`.

Comment: Whoops, you nailed it, that's exactly what I was doing ;). The world feels more sane again.

Comment: With the environment setting `PYTHONVERBOSE=2` you can see the order of module cleanup and attribute clearing.

Comment: But note that self.__class__.count and self.count are not the same thing. I've edited my post to make it clear.

Comment: @Peter: That is true, but that is tangential to the issue.  If you change everything to use `self.count`, then you are changing the nature of the code so the class-attribute issue is no longer an issue.  If you only *read* the value of `self.count` (in the final print) then it is in fact the same as `self.__class__.count` in this case.  Also, don't edit someone else's answer to clarify your own points.