# Python: can't invoke parent class destructor with super()

Tags: python, destructor, super

I can't invoke the destructor of the Parent class from the destructor of the Child class.
Please, check the code below:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'BaseClass->Destructor'

class DerivativeClass(BaseClass):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'DerivativeClass->Destructor'
        #Invoke destructor of the base class, it works 
        BaseClass.__del__(self)           
        #Doesn't work
        #super(DerivativeClass, self).__del__() 

instance = DerivativeClass()
```

When I use `super(DerivativeClass, self).__del__()` in `DerivativeClass.__del__()` I got the following error:

```
Exception TypeError: 'must be type, not None' in <bound method 
DerivativeClass.__del__ of <__main__.DerivativeClass object at 0xb73a682c>> ignored
```

**QUESTION:**

Why can't I use `super` in the destructor of the child class while it's perfectly fine in the constructor of the child class?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact reason, but note that `super(DerivativeClass, self)` returns an object of type `super`, not an instance of `BaseClass`. `__del__` probably makes some assumption about its first argument that is not valid for `super` objects.

Comment: Put a `print(DerivativeClass)` in front of `super...` and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Or add a `del instance` as last line to your code to ensure that the instance is thrown away before the class goes over the Jordan.

Comment: Odds are you don't need to use `__del__` at all. It is best to avoid it, unless you know you *really* need it.  See the good answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/865115/2096752) for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this happens only on runtime exit (because `DerivativeClass` is `None`).

This works fine:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'BaseClass->Destructor'

class DerivativeClass(BaseClass):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'DerivativeClass->Destructor'
        super(DerivativeClass, self).__del__() 

instance = DerivativeClass()
del instance
```

And this works fine too:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'BaseClass->Destructor'

class DerivativeClass(BaseClass):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'DerivativeClass->Destructor'
        super(type(self), self).__del__() 

instance = DerivativeClass()
```

Also this:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'BaseClass->Destructor'

class DerivativeClass(BaseClass):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'DerivativeClass->Destructor'
        super(DerivativeClass, self).__del__() 

def someScope ():
    instance = DerivativeClass()

someScope ()
```

---

In snippets 1 and 3, I make sure that the instance dies before the class. In snippet 2 I circumnavigate the whole issue in quite an ugly manner.

Comment: It makes sense, since the behavior upon exit of the program is quite unpredictable

Comment: +1 The common thread in all three examples is that they avoid using a global name that is (presumably) no longer in scope when the interpreter is exiting.