# Pythonic way to close connection-like objects in __del__

Tags: python

I'm working on a connection-like object which implements a context manager. Writing something like this is strongly encouraged:

```
with MyConnection() as con:
    # do stuff
```

Of course one can do this as well:

```
con = MyConnection()
# do stuff
con.close()
```

But failing to close the connection is rather problematic. So closing in the `__del__()` seems like a good idea:

```
def __del__(self):
    self.close()
```

This looks quite nice, but sometimes leads to errors:

```
Exception ignored in: [...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line xxx, in __del__()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

It appears as if sometimes the close method is already destroyed, when `__del__()` is called.

So I'm looking for a nice way to encourage python to close the connection properly on destruction. If possible I would like to avoid code duplication in `close()` and `__del__()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object

Comment: If you're writing a context manager, use `__exit__`

Comment: thanks for your comments - I know that using the context manager is a nice solution - yet users can't be forced to use it. I'd like to avoid system crashes if users fail to close connections properly.

Comment: To avoid code duplication, have `close` call `__del__`.  And don't get too wrapped up in protecting your users -- they are, after all, programmers and should be smart enough to use the API you have given them -- just make sure you have good docs, and the rest is on them.

Comment: Calling `__del__` in the close method is somewhat ugly as well. I think you are right - It's probably not a good idea to focus too much on users misusing the code. Especially when the code changes are rather hackish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to prevent the user from not closing the connection, you could just init it only in `__enter__` or you may add a flag spotting the fact it has not been initialized by a context manager. For instance, something like

```
class MyConnection(object):

    safely_initialized = False

    def __enter__(self):
        # Init your connection
        self.safely_initialized = True
        return self

    def do_something(self):
        if not self.safely_initialized:
            raise Exception('You must initialize the connection with a context manager!')
        # Do something

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        # Close your connection
```

That way the connection won't be initialized unless within a context manager.

Comment: So instead of trying to clean up after a poor choice on their part, don't even run unless they use the supported method.  Nice.

Comment: Yes, that would probably work. Yet it would force users to use the with statement. I'm not sure if I want to do that.

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far. Yet I'm not sure if I like it better than trying to nuke connections in the `__del__` method. This would lead to some lines of ugly code duplication, but does not force the user to use the with statement. It's not very important for me that the connections are closed properly - just having too many is not a good idea.

Comment: As the others mentionned, `__del__` should be avoided because it can lead to unpredictable results. So if you don't want to force the users, then you'll have to accept some not-well closed connections (or have a look at @ethan-furman answer).

Comment: Yes, it's probably not a good idea to use the `__del__` method for connection cleanups. I'll wait until tomorrow - if there are no more ideas I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee when `__del__` will actually run. Since you are using a `with` statement, use the `__exit__` method instead. `__exit__` will be called as soon as the `with` statement is finished, no matter how the statement completes (normally, with an exception, etc).

Comment: yes my current implementation uses a context manager and users are encouraged to use it. Yet I'm looking for a cleanup if users fail to use the context manager properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling `close` in `__del__`, and ignore any exceptions:

```
del __del__(self):
    try:
        self.close()
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Comment: yes, I thought about that, but I think this does not tackle the key problem. For me, calling the close method in del seems like a bad idea in general, since it is not guaranteed that this method even exits anymore.

Comment: @cel: If the interpreter is shutting down, you have no guarentees about anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is true you cannot force your users to use good programming techniques, and if they refuse to do so you cannot be responsible for them.

There is no guarantee of when `__del__` will be called -- in some Pythons it is immediate, in others it may not happen until interpreter shutdown.  So, while not a very good option, using [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html?highlight=atexit#atexit) may be viable -- just be sure that the function you register is smart enough to check if the resource has already been closed/destroyed.

Comment: Yes, it's true that I'm not responsible for bad programming - yet it's nice to avoid crashes and problems if possible. While it's true that I can't be sure that all connections are killed - most of them probably will. The rest will get nuked during interpreter shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

[`weakref.finalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize) lets you perform an action when an object is garbage collected, or the program exits. It's available from Python 3.4 onwards.

When you create your object you can make a call to `finalize()`, providing it a callback that cleans up the resources your object holds.

The Python docs provide [several examples of its use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#finalizer-objects):

```
>>> import weakref
>>> class Object:
...     pass
...
>>> kenny = Object()
>>> weakref.finalize(kenny, print, "You killed Kenny!")  
<finalize object at ...; for 'Object' at ...>
>>> del kenny
You killed Kenny!
```

And [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#comparing-finalizers-with-del-methods) of a class representing a temporary directory whose contents are deleted when:

- its `remove()` method is called
- it gets garbage collected
- program exits

Whichever happens first.

```py
class TempDir:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        self._finalizer = weakref.finalize(self, shutil.rmtree, self.name)

    def remove(self):
        self._finalizer()

    @property
    def removed(self):
        return not self._finalizer.alive
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define a `close()` method and call it on `is_open` condition both in `__exit__` and `__del__` methods as follows:

```py
class MyContext:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.is_open = False
        self.args = args
        self.open(*self.args)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __del__(self):
        self.close()
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()
    def open(self, *args):
        if not self.is_open:
            self.is_open = True
            print("opening: ", args)
        return self
    def close(self):
        if self.is_open:
            self.is_open = False
            print("closing: ", self.args)
```

---

Here is a usage example WITHOUT a context manager:

```py
def init_way():
    c = MyContext("path", "openparam")

init_way()
```

Possible output:

```py
opening:  ('path', 'openparam')
closing:  ('path', 'openparam')
```

---

And another example: using the same class as a context manager this time:

```py
def context_way():
    with MyContext("path", "openparam") as c:
        print("in with ...")

context_way()
```

Possible output:

```
opening:  ('path', 'openparam')
in with ...
closing:  ('path', 'openparam')
```