# Python - deconstructor does not delete object instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, instance

I have the following problem, i am an amateur user of Python scripting. I have created the following  class

```
 roof_height = 3.5 #m
 E = 30000*(10^3) #kN/m^2

 class Brace():
     _registry = []


     def __init__(self,name,coord,b,d, h = roof_height):
          print('Brace created.')
          Brace._registry.append(self)
          self.name  = name 
          self.coord = coord              # pass tuple in the form of (x,y)
          self.b     = b                  # //x global
          self.d     = d                  # //y global
          self.h     = h

      def __del__(self):
          print('Destructor called, Brace deleted.')
          Brace._registry.remove(self)


      def properties(self):
          print("properties of " + self.name + " calculated")
          As = self.b*self.d
          Iy = self.b*(self.d**3)*(1/12)
          Iz = (self.b**3)*(self.d)*(1/12)
          self.Iy =  Iy
          self.Iz =  Iz
          self.As =  As

    def stiffness(self):
        print("stiffnesses of " + self.name + " calculated")
        Kx = 12*E*self.Iy/self.h
        Ky = 12*E*self.Iz/self.h

        self.Kx = Kx
        self.Ky = Ky
```

I have created the _registry general property of the class so I can iterate through the objects, which works fine. The problems that I am facing are the following: 
1. When I am creating an object the print out

```
 'Brace created'
```

is displayed, but when I am deleting it the message

```
 'Destructor called, Brace deleted.'
```

is not displayed while the object is deleted, also the _registry list remains the same without deleting the object. The length of the list obviously remains the same.

2. How can I avoid creating the same instance twice with the same name, I mean how can I check for duplicate instances (same object name and attribute values) 
   Do I have to write a code for it or is there a builtin function that I can use?

Comment: "when i am deleting it" - how are you deleting the instance? Can you include this bit of your code?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you expect the `remove()` to do. Do you expect it to remove `self` (in this case, the `Brace` object) from the list ***and*** delete the object from memory, or do you expect it to just remove it from the list?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488705/is-relying-on-del-for-cleanup-in-python-unreliable and consider creating the methods required for a context manager.

Comment: @asongtoruin for example `brace1 = Brace('K1',(3,2),0.5,1.5)` for creating the object and `del brace1` for deleting it.  @ResetACK Yes i want to delete the object and remove it from the list.  @cdarke thanks will do.

Comment: `__del__` is probably not what you think it is - it is invoked by the garbage collector

Comment: `del x` simply deletes the *reference*. The `__del__` method of an object gets called when the reference count of an object becomes 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: __del__() might not be getting called for a number of reasons to do with garbage collection. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=del#object.__del__):

> Note del x doesn’t directly call x.__del__() — the former decrements
>   the reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when
>   x‘s reference count reaches zero. Some common situations that may
>   prevent the reference count of an object from going to zero include:
>   circular references between objects (e.g., a doubly-linked list or a
>   tree data structure with parent and child pointers); a reference to
>   the object on the stack frame of a function that caught an exception
>   (the traceback stored in sys.exc_info()[2] keeps the stack frame
>   alive); or a reference to the object on the stack frame that raised an
>   unhandled exception in interactive mode (the traceback stored in
>   sys.last_traceback keeps the stack frame alive). The first situation
>   can only be remedied by explicitly breaking the cycles; the second can
>   be resolved by freeing the reference to the traceback object when it
>   is no longer useful, and the third can be resolved by storing None in
>   sys.last_traceback. Circular references which are garbage are detected
>   and cleaned up when the cyclic garbage collector is enabled (it’s on
>   by default). Refer to the documentation for the gc module for more
>   information about this topic.

Rather than relying on the built-in memory management functionality, perhaps you could implement a bespoke function for freeing up resources once an object is no longer needed?

2: To avoid having two instances with the same name, use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. You helped me understand the problem with the circular references and the garbage_collector of python. Through your references i also found this [link](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python) which helped understand it a little better. For now i decided to remove the registry list and create a list with the objects that i want outside the class. In that way there are no references left and the destructor is called when the reference closes. I