# How to check if class is initialized using the with statement?

Tags: python-2.7, with-statement

I'm using the class example from this answer to make sure certain files are always cleaned up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/865272/651779

What I would like is that when I call

```
pacakge_object = PackageResource()
```

instead of

```
with PackageResource() as package_obj:
    # do stuff
```

it gives an error explaining this class can only be used with the `with` statement. Is there a way of knowing if the class was initialized with `with PackageResource() as package_obj:` instead of `pacakge_object = PackageResource()`?

Comment: I don't think there is, but why would you want to prevent anyone from using `package_object = PackageResource()` anyways? Just explain how to use it in the documentations. If somebody chooses to use it differently, they either know what they're doing, or it's their problem, not yours.

Comment: The class doesn't know what it's going to be assigned to or how, unless you do something horrible and fragile with `inspect`; just document that it's best used as a context manager, and reserve the right to laugh at people who ignore you, crash and burn!

Comment: You can take a look at [this article](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/), specially in the part *Implementing the Context Manager as a Class*. You may find something useful there.

Comment: @Christian that just tells you how to make a CM, which the OP has already done, not how to force the users to use the class in that way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so, there is nothing OP can use in that link?

Comment: @Christian nothing relevant to this question

Comment: @jonrsharpe What about Mark Jansen answer. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: @Christian what do you mean *"is it possible"*? Yes, it is. How does that related to the article you've linked to?

Comment: It is related in the part *"...Here are the exact steps taken by the Python interpreter when it reaches the with statement:..."*. There, they mention that the `__enter__` function is called, for example. That's why I meant by, *"You may find something useful here"* in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag in your `__enter__` function, and if any properties / methods of your class are called without that flag set, someone is cheating on you.