# How to specify clean up behavior of an object when it is garbage collected in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection

Say I have some class that manages a database connection. The user is supposed to call `close()` on instances of this class so that the db connection is terminated cleanly.

Is there any way in python to get this object to call `close()` if the interpreter is closed or the object is otherwise picked up by the garbage collector?

Edit: This question assumes the user of the object failed to instantiate it within a `with` block, either because he forgot or isn't concerned about closing connections.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object) can help you. Use your object with a `with` statement by implementing `__enter__` and `__exit__` method.

Comment: @Hackndo sorry, I should have specified that the question assumes the user forgot to instantiate the object within a `with` block.

Comment: You could try using `__del__`, but that is not guaranteed to be called if the object is still in scope when the program exits. The user really needs to be responsible and use `with`.

Comment: @chepner does `__del__` method get called sometimes when the program exits? If so I might as well throw a call to `close()` inside of `__del__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to ensure such a method is called if you don't trust users is using `__del__` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)). From the docs:

> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed.

Note that there are lots of issues that make using del tricky. For example, at the moment it is called, the interpreter may be shutting down already - meaning other objects and *modules* may have been destroyed already. See the notes and warnings for details.

---

If you really cannot rely on users to be consenting adults, I would prevent them from implicitly avoiding `close` - don't give them a public `open` in the first place. Only supply the methods to support `with`. If anybody explicitly digs into your code to do otherwise, they probably have a good reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

Define [`__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) and [`__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) methods on your class and then use it with the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with):

```
with MyClass() as c:
    # Do stuff
```

When the `with` block ends your `__exit__()` method will be called automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the question assumes the user failed to instantiate the object within a `with` block, because he either forgot to or didn't care about closing the connection.

Comment: You can probably put the behaviour you want in [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) if you really want to, but in my opinion `__enter__`, `__exit__` and `with` are a better fit. `__del__` might not get called in all circumstances, e.g. "It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits".