# How to run some thing before program ends in python

Tags: python

What's the suggested way to do just before the program ends in Python?

e.g. in c++, I can do something like

```
struct Cleanup { ~Cleanup() { ..do something..} };
....In some function... {
  static Cleanup cleanup; // this will be cleaned when program ends.
}
```

(I'm not sure whether the way above is a legitimate way in C++ but it seems working for me).

Comment: Try `with` statements and context managers.

Comment: sorry to hijack the question, but I think this would help responders: can someone explain what is happening in the cpp snippet?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/865272/1189040)

Answer (score 2):

Since you were specifically asking about the *program* finishing you may also want to look at the built-in `atexit` module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Answer (score 0):

Search about python destructor.

```
class Package:
    ...
    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pass
```

or decorator

```
@SomeDecorator
def function():
    pass

def SomeDecorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # after func
return wrapper
```